# WPF Multi-Binding / Aggregate Binding to Collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a Control that I want to automatically disappear if another control has no *visibile* children.  I'm not sure how to implement that though.  I feel as though I need to create a binding that returns bindings for each child element's visible property and then aggregates them into a MultiValueConverter.  I think it is working but it seems as though when I add items to my collection, the collection binding isn't being re-evaluated.  Has anyone done this before?

Below is my code:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BindingExpander x:Key="BindingExpander"/>
        <local:TestConverter x:Key="TestConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="237,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TestConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="lstItems" Path="Items" Converter="{StaticResource BindingExpander}" ConverterParameter="Visibility"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.Visibility>
    </Button>

    <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="601,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" DisplayMemberPath="Content"/>
```

and:

```
public class TestConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var ret = Visibility.Collapsed;

        foreach (var item in values) {
            if(item is IEnumerable IE) {
                foreach (var Child in IE) {

                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class BindingExpander : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var ret = new List<Binding>();
        if(value is IEnumerable IE) {
            foreach (var item in IE) {
                ret.Add(new Binding(parameter.ToString()) {
                    Source = item,
                    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
                });
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

````

Comment: What control do you want to hide and when exactly do you want to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Control that I want to automatically disappear if another
>   control has no visibile children..

Simply create a Boolean property which reports the status of what the other control is binding to such as:

```
public bool HasItems { get { return _SomeArray?.Any(); }}
```

*This property can be as elaborate as needed, but a basic one above for the example is shown.*

Then bind the visibility flag of the control in question to the `HasItems`.

Note that the `HasItems` does not have the plumbing for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In the code(s) where items are added to the `_SomeArray` simply put in a call to `PropertyChanged("HasItems")`

---

On my blog I provide a basic example of that ([Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)) which looks like this where someone would bind to `IsMemebershipAtMax` such as what you are doing:

```
   public bool IsMembershipAtMax 
    {
        get { return MemberCount > 3; }
    }
    public int MemberCount 
    { 
        get { return _MemberCount; }
        set
        {
            _MemberCount = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("IsMembershipAtMax");
        } 
    }

    public List<string> Members 
    { 
        get { return _Members; }
        set { _Members = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
    }
```